# JMeter - kick off a set number of jobs and then monitor state

Tags: java, jmeter

Does JMeter have a construct of kicking of 200 jobs concurrently and then checking for the completion of these 200 jobs once they have all been kicked off?

Currently I'm using 1 thread to kick off the entire 200 jobs which is fine.

However I'm not sure how I can track the state from the 200 jobs and then execute a getState HTTP call.

Is this the case for spinning up 200 threads and having each thread check the state of its own job?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter acts on [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol level which in its turn uses [TCP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/TCP) as underlying transport which

> guarantees the delivery of data and packets in the same order as they were sent.

So basically JMeter sends a request, waits for response and measures time in-between.

If you testing an application which assumes some asynchronous job, i.e. on first request you get response that job has been started and can query the status later on I would recommend the following:

1. Start a job normally using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. If you need to start multiple jobs concurrently you can use [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to guarantee that they will be executed at exactly the same moment.
2. Monitor its status using another HTTP Request sampler under [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) which is needed to exit the loop when job status changes
3. You can wrap the whole sequence into [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) so JMeter would sum up all the time in between starting and finishing the job.